# Week number of month from date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this, and format of column `date` is `yyyy-mm-dd` :

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|order_id|product_id|seller_id|      date|pieces_sold|       bill_raw_text|
+--------+----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|     668|    886059|     3205|2015-01-14|         91|pbdbzvpqzqvtzxone...|
|    6608|    541277|     1917|2012-09-02|         44|cjucgejlqnmfpfcmg...|
|   12962|    613131|     2407|2016-08-26|         90|cgqhggsjmrgkrfevc...|
|   14223|    774215|     1196|2010-03-04|         46|btujmkfntccaewurg...|
|   15131|    769255|     1546|2018-11-28|         13|mrfsamfuhpgyfjgki...|
+--------+----------+---------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I would like to create and append a column that has week number of month. Meaning a month a four weeks, and I would like to calculate that for all my dates.

Here's what I did:

```
sales_table.select(
    '*',
    F.date_format("date", "W").alias('week_month')
).show(5)
```

And the error is:

```
An error occurred while calling o140.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to recognize 'W' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter. 1) You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0. 2) You can form a valid datetime pattern with the guide from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkLegacyFormatter$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkLegacyFormatter$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:165)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.validatePatternString(TimestampFormatter.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.TimestampFormatter$.getFormatter(TimestampFormatter.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.TimestampFormatter$.apply(TimestampFormatter.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DateFormatClass.$anonfun$formatter$1(datetimeExpressions.scala:646)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DateFormatClass.formatter$lzycompute(datetimeExpressions.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DateFormatClass.formatter(datetimeExpressions.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DateFormatClass.doGenCode(datetimeExpressions.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.$anonfun$genCode$3(Expression.scala:146)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
..
..
..
```

How do I get week number of month from date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in error log, Set the below property in your **`spark session`**.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

sales_table.show()
#+----------+
#|      date|
#+----------+
#|2015-01-14|
#+----------+
sales_table.select('*',F.date_format("date", "W").alias('week_month')).show(5)
#+----------+----------+
#|      date|week_month|
#+----------+----------+
#|2015-01-14|         3|
#+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy LEGACY
```

to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

Unfortunately, in the latest version of Spark, 'W' is no longer supported in the datetime format. But you can still recover legacy behaviour by the above setting.